# mousemove event loses track when mouse is over an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, nwjs

I'm trying to track the mouse X and Y coorddinates in a project of mine made using NW.js, but, whenever the mouse goes over an iframe present in the page(which occupies roughly 50% of the page's height and all the width), the mousemove event(document.body.addEventListener("mousemove",console.log);) loses track of it, not firing any more updates. How can I fix that? I need to be able to track the whole page.

Comment: no, mousemove events do not stop, but they are sent back to the iframe

Comment: well when I tested here(note: the mousemove event is on the main page not inside the iframe), it would stop firing whenever the mouse got inside the iframe. I checked the devtools and nothing was showing up

Comment: it is the iframe which receives the mousemove events, not the parent page